# minimal even partition among the ones $\geq$ a given partition

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Let $N$ be an even integer. A *partition* of $N$ is a sequence $(a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_N)$ of integers such that $a_1 \geq a_2 \geq \cdots \geq a_N \geq 0$, and $\sum_{j=1}^Na_j =N$.

Let $\mathscr P_N$ be the set of partitions of $N$. A partition $\nu \in \mathscr P_N$ is said to be *even* if $\nu = (\nu_1,\nu_2,\cdots \nu_N)$ satisfy $\nu_i$ is even for $i=1,2,\cdots, N$.

The order "$\leq$" is defined as follows. Let $\nu^1 =(\nu^1_1,\nu^1_2,\cdots,\nu^1_N)$, $\nu^2=(\nu^2_1,\nu^2_2,\cdots,\nu^2_N) \in \mathscr P_N$. We say that $\nu^1 \leq \nu^2$ if $\sum_{j=1}^i \nu^1_j \leq \sum_{j=1}^i \nu^2_j$ for $i =1,2,\cdots,N$. (It is easy to notice that $\mathscr P_N$ has a unique maximal element, which is $(N,0,0,\cdots,0)$, and a unique minimal element, which is $(1,1,\cdots,1)$.)

Let $\lambda \in \mathscr P_N$. Let $$\Gamma =\{\nu \in \mathscr P_N | \lambda \leq \nu \text{ and } \nu \text{ is even}\}.$$

Then does $\Gamma$ always have a unique minimal element (under "$\leq$")? Is there any standard process for me to find a minimal element of $\Gamma$ from $\lambda$?

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: How do you compare two partitions of different size? And do you do $\le$ coordinatewise? and BTW, partitions are unordered normally, do you sort them by size internally? so that $1+1+3$ for 5 would be represented by $(1,1,3)$ ?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, thank you very much for the comment. Now I have added some definitions in the question.

Comment: I need another clarification, are you asking for minimal element in "less than or equal to" relation or under "greater than or equal to" relation. Because if it's the latter case, then minimal element refers to the maximum element right? And for which the answer is simply (N,0,....,0).

Comment: @shwetha: Thank you much for the comment. I will explain further that I am not asking for $(N,0,\cdots, 0)$.

Comment: This is the dominance order, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

To find a minimal element:

For convenience, let $\lambda=(\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\cdots, \lambda_N).$
If $\lambda $ is itself even then it is a minimal element. Otherwise, at least one $\lambda_i $  is odd.  Since N is even, and $\sum_{i=1}^{N}{\lambda_i}=N$, number  of $\lambda_i $ which are odd, is even. Now to find the minimal element $m=(m_1, m_2,\cdots, m_N)$ from $\lambda $:
Step-1: Keep/Retain all the even $\lambda_i$ as such in $m .$
Step-2: Add 1 to the first odd $\lambda_j$ and subtract 1 from the immediate next odd $\lambda_k .$ Do this till all $\lambda_i' s $ become even.
Step-3: Rearrange the resulting values so that $m_1\geq m_2\geq....\geq m_N.$
Does it help you?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't think $(\mathscr P_N, \leq)$ is totally ordered. For example, When $N=6$, $\nu^1=(4,1,1,0,0,0)$ and $\nu^2=(3,3,0,0,0,0)$, then $\nu^1_1>\nu^2_1$, but $\nu^1_1+\nu^1_2<\nu^2_1+\nu^2_2$. So these two are not comparable under "$\leq$". I understand the process you have described. But I am wondering if there is a proof for it really being minimal. Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: Yes, I just missed it. Can you give such an example for even partition, pls? And in those steps am just trying to find an element just greater than $\lambda.$ And I'll try to improve my answer...

Comment: Thanks again. For even partitions, let $N=12$, $\nu^1=(8,2,2)$ and $\nu^2=(6,6)$ ($0$'s omitted). Then it is noticed that these two are not comparable under "$\leq$".